# Character width exceeded

Tags: sql, netezza

I create a master table with column A, column B, and column C. Whenever I try to insert row from another table using the command:

```
INSERT INTO MASTER
select * from Table B
```

I get the error message "Character Width exceeded". I am not sure why.

Comment: What database are you using?  What's netezza?

Comment: [Netezza](http://www.netezza.com/) is a very popular data warehouse tool. It competes with Teradata.

Comment: Compare definitions of `Master` and `TableB` tables. Some char or varchar field(s) probably differ in size.

Comment: The error message is very clear. You are trying to insert values that have a bigger size than the destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the one or more column size of `Table B` is larger than the respective column size of `MASTER`.

For e.g. - `Table B`'s `column1` might be `VARCHAR(255)` and `MASTER`'s `column A` might be less than 255.

Comment: I changed the varchar statement for the master table to varchar(40)

Comment: Make the columns of MASTER similar to that of Table B.

Comment: I can only see the type of variable not the number of characters

Answer (score 0):

Check if the structure of table MASTER is **exactly** the same as the table B.

Probably is a problem in which MASTER.colx is a string(20) and B.colx is a string(25), or may be is a charset problem (unicode/latin-1/utf-8/iso-8859-x)

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating the table MASTER as:

```
select *
  into master
  from tableB
 where 1=0
```

This will guarantee that the column datatypes are the same between the two tables. Then you can try your insert again.